# strength of each pattern

Tags: linux, bash, file

linux `file -l` command lists the magic numbers of files and a parameter called called "strength". AFAIK, magic numbers are the unique identifiers for the file types. but what is the strength parameter?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on Unix&Linux. Also, the manpage spells out the meaning quite clearly.

Comment: It actually only mentions how to modify it.  I'm currently having trouble matching a new file type registration versus an existing one that involves this additional instruction.  Still looking this might help - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154096/file1-and-magic5-prioritizing-a-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all file magic relies on the first two bytes.  Read the dirty details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic).